Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'choices') in React application using OpenAI API
Edit: Issue was solved
I'm working on a React application where I'm using the OpenAI API to communicate with the AI. In my application, I'm trying to send user input to the API and receive a response from the AI. However, I'm encountering the following error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'choices')
    at sendMsgToOpenAI (openai.js:15:1)
    at async handleSend

Here's the relevant portion of my code:
App component (App.js)
import './App.css';
import AIlogo from './assets/chatgpt.svg';
import addBtn from './assets/add-30.png';
import msgIcon from './assets/message.svg';
import home from './assets/home.svg';
import saved from './assets/bookmark.svg';
import upgrade from './assets/rocket.svg';
import sendBtn from './assets/send.svg';
import userIcon from './assets/user.svg';
import AIchat from './assets/chatgptLogo.svg';
import { sendMsgToOpenAI } from './openai';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const[input, setInput] = useState("");

const handleSend = async() => {

  const res = await sendMsgToOpenAI(input);
  console.log(res);
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className ="sideBar">
     <div className ="upperSide">
     
     <div className ="upperSideTop"><img src={AIlogo} alt="Logo" className="logo"/><span className="brand">Eclipse AI</span>  
     <button className="midBtn"><img src={addBtn} alt="" className="addBtn" />New Chat</button>
      
     <div className="upprtSideBottom">
      
    <button className="query"><img src={msgIcon} alt=""/> What is Programming ?</button>
    <button className="query"><img src={msgIcon} alt=""/> How to use an API ?</button>
    </div>
     </div>
     </div>


   
        
       <div className ="lowerSide">
       <div className ="listItems"><img src={home} alt="" className="listitemsImg" />Home</div>
       <div className ="listItems"><img src={saved} alt="" className="listitemsImg" />Saved</div>
       <div className ="listItems"><img src={upgrade} alt="" className="listitemsImg" />Upgrade to Pro</div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div className ="main">
<div className="chats">

<div className="chat">
 <img src={AIchat} alt=""/><p className="txt">uncountable noun [usu with supp] You can use stuff to refer to things such as a substance, a collection of things, events, or ideas, or the contents of something in a general way without mentioning the thing itself by name.</p>
 <img src={userIcon} alt=""/><p className="txt">uncountable noun [usu with supp] You can use stuff to refer to things such as a substance, a collection of things, events, or ideas, or the contents of something in a general way without mentioning the thing itself by name.</p>
</div>
</div>
 



<div className="chatFooter">
  <div className="inp">
    <input type="text" placeholder='Message EclipseAI' value={input} onChange={(e)=>{setInput(e.target.value)}} /><button className="send" onClick={handleSend}><img src={sendBtn} alt="send-icon" /></button>

  </div>
  <p>This page of EclipseAI is still under development, including the user interface.</p>
</div>
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

OpenAI function (openai.js):
const OpenAI = require('openai');

const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: 'Key in here', dangerouslyAllowBrowser: true });

export async function sendMsgToOpenAI(message) {
    const res = await openai.completions.create({
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct',
        prompt: message,
        temperature: 0.7,
        max_tokens: 256,
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0,
        presence_penalty: 0
    });
    return res.data.choices[0].text;
}

The error occurs when I try to call the sendMsgToOpenAI function. Specifically, it happens when trying to access res.data.choices[0].text.
What I've tried:
Checked that the API key is correct and authorized for the model I'm using.
Verified that I'm using the correct API endpoint.
Additional Information:
I'm using gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct as the model.
Has anyone else encountered this error or know how to resolve it? Any help would be appreciated.
Solution:
Replacing return res.data.choices[0].text
With return res.choices[0].text

Attempting to read choices from res.data is causing the error because res.data is undefined. What does res return?

res returns the response

Right, but what does that response actually contain?

To tag along what @mykaf asked - are you sure it's res.data.choices[0], and not res.choices[0]? The reason for my question - according to the docs (the part after "You should get a response back that resembles the following"), res should be a JSON, and not an array.

@Akin post your solution as a answer
